# How to start Google Assistant programmatically?

Tags: android, google-assist-api

I have tried every simple combo I have found but not sure how to do this.
I even tried to simulate the home long press but you get google now voice, lookint at logcat it shows this

com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity

but not sure if this is what I am looking for or how to replicate it.

Answer (score 15):

This works:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Comment: Can you ask question along with the intent ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND?

Answer (score 1):

So I've been trying to do the same thing, and just discovered something when I'm trying to launch the Assistant with an Intent like this:

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        launchIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
        launchIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Although this doesn't throw an ActivityNotFoundException, it does throw a Permission Denial. This is shown to happen because Google Assistant must be launched from the googlequicksearchbox package from above. Hopefully this will change when/if they release an API for it. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Yes, i tried that already. You can bypass that with ROOT. and it works just fine but requires root.

Comment: `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox` is not Google Assistant. Its the Google app.