# how to simulate a button click on an app icon/shortcut

Tags: android

I wonder how it is possible to simulate a button click to launch an app through its shortcut? I have seen automation apps such as Automagic (perhaps also Tasker) do this. 
Are they using AccessibilityServices? If yes, how would I call such a shortcut -do I use "performGlobalAction()"?

Edit:
What I really after is to emulate/simulate a click on a button or a shortcut which apps such as Tasker can do. For instance, Google Assistant cannot be opened programatically (see [How to start Google Assistant programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709191/how-to-start-google-assistant-programatically)) due to permission denail. However, it can be opened by clicking on a shortcut on the screen opened according to the following instructions: https://www.ytechb.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-any-android-lollipop-device-without-root/

With Tasker I can then add an action which opens this shortcut. Now I am wondering how Tasker does this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch another android app by using an `Intent`. To get the launch intent for another application you can use the

```
Context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(String packagename);
```

If this is not null, then the app is installed on the device and you can launch it. If you want to get a list of other apps on the device you can use

```
Context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(Intent intent, int flags);
```

You can find more information of these by looking at the [PackageManager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: What you say is OK but as far as I know not applicable in my case. Perhaps I was to vague. I have edited my question and hopefully this explains better what I am asking