# How to open Google Assistant from an app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-assistant-sdk

I am relatively new to android and I am working on an app which requires me to open google assistant from my own application. I do not intend to add conversations and my sole purpose is to mimic the "Home Button Long Press" which opens up Google Assistant. Any way I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709191/how-to-start-google-assistant-programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start Google Assistant programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709191/how-to-start-google-assistant-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this `ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND` that that activity action is to start Voice Command.

In your code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. It works

```
    `$`
    startActivity(new 
  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.data=Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.googleassistant")
activity.startActivity(intent)
```