# Send Google Assistant (Specifically the Assistant, not any other search method) a command from an Android app

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to send the Google Assistant a command (specifically "Good Morning") from my app when you press a button. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826826/sending-commands-to-google-assistant-from-android-app/47052907#47052907?newreg=5ce97917a7314756b61649a032e92c10) that asks a similar question, but the "Correct Answer" does not work. The answer provided opens up a Google Search, but NOT the Assistant. This means that when I send it "Good Morning" it simply Google searches "Good Morning" instead of playing my daily briefing (which is my intended goal). The intent in the question (`Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND`) opens the Assistant. However, what extra do I have to set to send it a command? `intent.putExtra("query", "Good Morning");` does not work.

Comment: [android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html) & [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709191/how-to-start-google-assistant-programatically#43700669)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start Google Assistant programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709191/how-to-start-google-assistant-programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is NO way to pass a command to your Voice Assistant. There is [no input for long presses](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS) or [voice commands](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND), which are the two intents I would have used to complete this task. Whether this because of a security reason or because the Assistant is still new, is unknown. However, what is known is that this functionality currently does not exist.